# Is good to use object configuration into a Singleton?

Tags: java, hibernate, singleton

I know this would seem to be something blasphemic and it (may) break the singleton nature so, please, don't hurt me! I'm just asking.

Assuming that the example below is just a random situation (and actually MY SITUATION, coincidence? I don't think so...) my question is generic.

I've got a singleton class like this:

```
    public class SingleSessionFactory {

    private SingleSessionFactory() {
    }

    private static class SingleSessionHelper {

        private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY = getSingleSession();

        private static SessionFactory getSingleSession() {

            if (SESSION_FACTORY == null) {
                Configuration hConf = new Configuration();

                //hibernate configuration I wish to set by an object or sth dynamic not hard-coded!

                try {
                    return hConf.buildSessionFactory();
                } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return SESSION_FACTORY;
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getInstance() {
        return SingleSessionHelper.SESSION_FACTORY;
    }

}
```

which instead of the line `//hibernate config...bla bla bla & bla...` i used to call the `setProperty(..)` and `addAnnotatedClass(..)` hard-coded.

I wish to know if it's good to use a custom property object (by instance: `MyHibernateConfiguration` class) to use inside my `getSingleSession()`, which inside some attribute to store Hibernate properties (as `"hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"`) and annotated class. Injecting or passing or...whatever... in this way "all that things" could be passed dynamically and that would be veeeeeryveryvery cool, isn't it right?

Anyway:

Q: Is it possible?

A1: Yeah of course! And the bestt way to do that is...

A2: NO! This is madness! I'm gonna underrate this question and send you to hell! Muha-ha-ha-haaaa... (yeah, evil laugh...)

That's all folk!

Comment: Maybe a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you want to achive? It seems to me that you want to have a singleton object with your hibernate configuration, yes?

Comment: @JFPicard I'll post there asap, thanks.@G. Demecki...with my Hibernate configuration inside an object INSIDE the singleton. I guess if it's possible to pass a configuration object to my singleton. I don't want to set parameters hard coded in there.